# Node.js stops responding when using serialport

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I'm using node.js for the first time with a simple website to control a motor.

On the website are 2 buttons: "Left" and "Right". You have to press and hold the "Left" or "Right" button to turn the motor. When you let the button go the motor stops.
The motor is connected to an Arduino on the serialport on the server.
It works, but

## Problem

When I use it on my phone and spam the buttons the server sometimes stops responding for everyone until I restart the server. I thought the functions were called too fast because of the WiFi latency. So I tried calling the functions in the Chrome console.

```
LeftPressed();LeftReleased();LeftPressed();LeftReleased();
```

And indeed, after running them a few times the server stops responding.
No error, no crash..

When I remove `motorPort.write(message);` keeps the server responding.

**How can I prevent the server from stopping to respond?**

## Client (Javascript in browser)

```
function LeftPressed() {      
    socket.emit('steer', { left: true });
}
function LeftReleased() {       
    socket.emit('steer', { left: false });
}
function RightPressed() {        
    socket.emit('steer', { right: true });
}
function RightReleased() {        
    socket.emit('steer', { right: false });
}
```

## Server (node.js)

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server)    
const motorPort = new SerialPort('/dev/arduinoUnoMicroUSB', {
    baudrate: 9600,
});

app.use(express.static('web'));
server.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log("Server running...");
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
    socket.on('steer', function (data) {
        var message = "2"; //stop   

        if (data.left != undefined) {
            console.log("Left: " + data.left); //log to Console (below)
            if (data.left) {
                message = "1" //turn left
            }
        }    

        if (data.right != undefined) {
            console.log("Right: " + data.right);
            if (data.right) {
                message = "3"; //turn right
            }
        }    

        motorPort.write(message); //send message over serial port            
    });   
});
```

**Console output example: "Left" button clicked**

```
Server running...
Left: true        //pressed   (motor turning left)
Left: false       //released  (motor stops)
```

Comment: try to run with sudo

Comment: @Adiii Same problem with sudo

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: @Adiii KDE neon (based on Ubuntu)

Comment: and version of ubuntu pls

Comment: Description:    KDE neon User Edition 5.10
Release:        16.04

Comment: you  need to first port.on then port.wrtemessager           port.on('open', function() {
  port.write('main screen turn on', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
    }
    console.log('message written');
  });
});
 
// open errors will be emitted as an error event 
port.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message);
})

Comment: @Adiii, I added your code. It's the same, and no errors.

Comment: @Adiii I also tried in Windows, and I have the same results.

Comment: How did you set up the serial communication on your device?

Comment: Perhaps it's related to this issue: https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/issues/1188 (either that, or CATS)

Comment: @sBanda [Arduino code I used](https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/F0J/53XT/I49RNEAC/F0J53XTI49RNEAC.ino) that I [found here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Modules-L298N-Dual-H-Bridge-Motor-Controll/)

Comment: @robertklep On your url is this code suggested, but what is that callback in port.flush? I tried without it, with again the same results

http://i.imgur.com/z01cRTl.png

Comment: @MatMis it's a function that gets called when the data has been flushed. It's going to be difficult to implement in your code, though.

Comment: @robertklep Ok thanks, I tried passing an empty function as callback, but with the same results.

Comment: @MatMis ideally, you should test writing a new message only if the old one has been flushed, but like I said, that's not really easy to implement in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this. It's not 100% perfect, but at least the server keeps responding. If you think there is a better way, I am always open for improvements.

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const motorPort = new SerialPort('/dev/arduinoUnoMicroUSB', {
    baudrate: 9600,
});

app.use(express.static('web'));
server.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log("Server running...");
});
var ready = true;
var NotSendMessages = [];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('steer', function (data) {
        var message = "2"; //stop   
        if (data.left != undefined) {
            console.log("Left: " + data.left);
            if (data.left) {
                message = "1" //turn left
            }
        }

        if (data.right != undefined) {
            console.log("Right: " + data.right);
            if (data.right) {
                message = "3"; //turn right
            }
        }
        if (!ready) {
            console.log("cats!!!");
            NotSendMessages.push(message);
        } else {
            send(message);
        }
    });
});
function send(message) {
    motorPort.write(message, function () {
        ready = false;
        motorPort.drain(function () {
            motorPort.flush(function () {
                ready = true;
            });
        });
    });
}
setInterval(function () {
    if (NotSendMessages.length > 0 && ready) {
        send(NotSendMessages.shift());
    }
}, 50);
```